# Set Authentication Method in SwiftMailer 4.0.6

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Swiftmailer seems to default to crammd5 for SMTP authentication which is great but we have an SMTP server that requires PLAIN authentication (over SSL) and I can't seem to find a way in 4.x to set which authentication method to use. Apparently it was possible in 3.x but I can't find a way to do it in 4.x. I see there is a plain auth class but I've looked through the code and can't find a way to set it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided to me at: http://groups.google.com/group/swiftmailer/browse_thread/thread/422a409989c8acf1

```
$transport->setAuthMode('PLAIN');
```